# exe'шник программы не запускается на других компах

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте.

Написал программу для препода, он скинул себе exe'шник и у него он не запустился выдав ошибку "Не найден компонент vclx60.bpl" который как выяснилось лежит в C: Windows System. У препода Builder не установлен и файла этого в соответствующей директории нету.
Весь Project весит 2Mb, а exe'шник 50Кб, мб в нем чего то не хватает?
Я делал прогу на XP, а у него стоит 7ка.

Comment: В каком компиляторе  делаешь exe'шник


Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь то, для того чтобы скомпилировать все в exe в свойствах проекта нужно выключить "Build with runtime packages" и "Dynamic RTL". Иначе необходимо будет еще и библиотеки с exeшником носить

Comment: После изменений, о которых пишет уважаемый @Dmitrii необходимо построить проект заново:  в меню выбрать Build Project.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй скинуть компонент в папку с программой! и тогда должен открыться! У меня был такой случай! Но по идее он не должен выдавать ошибку!

Comment: Пробовал, начинает требовать другой, таким образом придется все RTL скинуть, одному бгу известно сколько их и где они находятся(